# BuildMaster using MSBuild 15.0

Tags: msbuild, buildmaster

How do I target MSBuild 15.0 on my server? I have 15.0 installed on the server but my project is still building with 14.0. I know that Microsoft has made some changes to the directory locations and no longer uses the registry values with 15.0.

I found 15.0 installed in the following locations:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild

And I have the .Net framework 4.6.2 installed here:
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319"

Thanks!

Product: BuildMaster

Version: 5.7.2

Update 1:

Responding to @emiel-koning, I tried to specify $MSBuildToolsPath in the build step using:

`set $MSBuildToolsPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin;`

But I get this error:
*error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(VSToolsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0" . These search paths are defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe.Config". Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.*

Update 2:

Could I be missing something installed on my build server? I installed [Visual Studio Build Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15) which gave me the MSBuild 15.0 but not the WebApplication.targets file from the error above

**SOLUTION**

I fix my issues by also installing "Web development build tools" component. I also set the $MSBuildToolsPath at the server level until I can roll out the new MSBuild globally.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is handled by the `ToolsVersion` attribute of the project file. This should be what is used if the below configuration is not specified.

In BuildMaster specifically, you can override this value per-server on the Administration > BuildMaster Extensions > Windows SDK > Configuration tab. Click on `$MSBuildToolsPath` (and optionally override at a specific scope) with a value of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`

#### Response to Updates #1 & #2:

First, don't set that variable in the plan itself (otherwise you'd have to set it in every plan). Set it in the manner I described above. Personally, I always specify its value at the server level since each server may have it installed in a different location.

As for Microsoft.WebApplication.targets, I think the only supported method of building web application projects is to have Visual Studio installed on the build server; though in the past I've just copied the targets from my local installation (C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications) into the path that MSBuild is expecting them to be.

Comment: Note that the `ToolsVersion` attribute only helps discovering installed toolsets, not the MSBuild version itself. this is crucial for msbuild 15+ projects relying on new file syntax and capabilities - e.g. .NET Core projects.

Comment: Interesting, that would explain why it's rarely worked for me (and I always end up specifying which one to use). From the [VS MSBuild docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-toolset-toolsversion): "When a ToolsVersion value is defined in a project file, MSBuild uses that value to determine the values of the Toolset properties that are available to the project. One Toolset property is $(MSBuildToolsPath), which specifies the path of the .NET Framework tools."

Comment: `$(MSBuildToolsPath)` also doesn't help if an "sdk-style" project was loaded by msbuild 14 or even msbuild 4, since it couldn't even parse the project file (`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">…</Project>`).
Also, the `ToolsVersion` property is now optional on projects in MSBuild 15.

Comment: Though it might just work for the OP if the projects are still compatible with MSBuild 14

Comment: I have the ToolsVersion set to 15.0 in my project file. Here is the excerpt:


`<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />`

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [`$MSBuildToolsPath`](http://inedo.com/support/documentation/buildmaster/reference/functions/server/msbuildtoolspath) to specify the correct path to MSBuild?